# Handling inline URLs with Next.js

Tags: javascript, url, path, hyperlink, next.js

I'm building an ecommerce platform where users will be using both our domain and their own domains like below.

`ourplatform.com/username`

`theirdomain.com`

I'd like to set the inline links depend on the domain they're entering the site. If it's our domain it should be `/username/page` or if it's their domain it should be just `/page`.

This is what I have so far. Only adding username if the domain is our platform.

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

const customPath = ({ username }) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window.location !== 'ourplatform.com'
      ? '/'
      : `/${username}`
  }
}

export default ({ username }) => {
  const link = customPath({ username })
  return (
    <Link href={link}>
      Home
    </Link>
  )
}
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.
```

How can I set different `href` links for different domains?

Answer (score 1):

You're correctly limiting the evaluation of `window.location` to the client-side phase, but you'll still need to have `customPath()` return a value for the `<Link />` component during the server-side compilation phase. Without a returned value, the `link` constant will be set to `undefined`.

```js
const customPath = ({ username }) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window.location.hostname !== 'ourplatform.com' // include `.hostname`
      ? '/'
      : `/${username}`
  }
  return '/' // return something to satisfy server-side compilation
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but got this error this time. `Warning: Prop href did not match. Server: "" Client: "/"`. This doesn't affect the UI but I'm wondering is there any other approaches out there. For example I'm adding the header `add_header x-domain "theirdomain.com";` to the domains with Nginx and would like to know that we can use that in Next.js. Maybe in `_middleware.js`? So if `x-domain` is not ourdomain.com then use different hrefs.

Comment: @ozgrozer The middleware approach could be worth pursing since you'd have access to the `headers` and `nextUrl` properties in the `NextRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly using `typeof window !== 'undefined'` to access `window.location`, I'd recommend you handle the `customPath` logic inside a `useEffect` to prevent server-side rendering mismatches.

Here's a custom hook that handles the custom path logic, without throwing any errors/warnings.

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

function useCustomPath({ username }) {
    const [customPath, setCustomPath] = useState('/') // Default path during SSR

    useEffect(() => {
        const path = window.location.hostname !== 'ourplatform.com' ? '/' : `/${username}`
        setCustomPath(path) // Set appropriate path on the client-side
    }, [username])

    return customPath
}

export default ({ username }) => {
    const link = useCustomPath({ username })
    
    return (
        <Link href={link}>
            Home
        </Link>
    )
}
```